# JQuery selector - #ElementId not working just ElementId is fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I am having some issues showing a div that i am hiding.  For some reason the #ElementId selector isnt working but if i just use ElementId it works.

Jquery 1.7.1 also I am using JQuery ui.

```
$('CreateGroup').show("fold"); // this works fine
$('#CreateGroup').show("fold"); // this fails with cannot call show on undefined

 <div id="CreateGroup" style="display: none">Hi!</div>
```

What's going on?

Thanks

Comment: What you're saying is not possible - http://jsfiddle.net/EU3jN/

Comment: perhaps create a http://jsfiddle.net/ with the code that isnt working ...

Comment: @Piercy, chances are your `$()` function comes from Prototype, not jQuery. Are you including both libraries in your page?

Comment: $('#CreateGroup').show("fold"); is there any error in this? i checked in my demo , work perfect

Comment: What you're saying doesn't make sense so there must be something else going on. Can you post more code or replicate the behaviour in a jsfiddle?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I believe it's used elsewhere in the product so this is a possibility. I'll try the long way with jQuery('#blah') and see.  Any chance you could mention this as an answer other wise if it's correct I cannot accept it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi seems you where correct :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Piercy, chances are your $() function comes from Prototype, not jQuery. Are you including both libraries in your page? – Frédéric Hamidi Mar 2 at 12:21

This was correct it was prototype interfering.  If I use the fully jQuery qualifier it works.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the element is already created when you call the function?

try this to ensure it to run after the DOM is ready:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
 $('#CreateGroup').show("fold");
});
```

More info:

[.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 0):

Both should fail.

Your code is not possible since you are not using the `document.load`event (aka `$(function(){});` aka `$('document').ready()`.

The node have not yet been defined when the script is called.

This would work however:

```
<div id="CreateGroup" style="display: none">Hi!</div>
<script type="text/javascript">$('#CreateGroup').show("fold");</script>
```

Since it's invoked AFTER the node definition.

You don't how to worry about that if you use the mentioned load methods.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#CreateGroup').show("fold"); 
    });
</script>

<div id="CreateGroup" style="display: none">Hi!</div>
```

That will work since the script is not executed until the whole document have been loaded.